# Getting conda verification error with libtiff library while creating a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, conda, libtiff

libtiff is not allowing to create virtual environment or any package that installs libtiff. I tried in conda versions 4.6.1 and 4.5.12. I also tried uninstall and reinstall anaconda. 
below is the error:

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for libtiff located at C:\Users\devrana\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libtiff-4.0.9-h36446d0_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/tiff.dll'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for libtiff located at C:\Users\devrana\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libtiff-4.0.9-h36446d0_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/tiff2pdf.exe'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for libtiff located at C:\Users\devrana\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\libtiff-4.0.9-h36446d0_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/tiffcrop.exe'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

I have tried uninstall and reinstall anaconda. Tried different versions of conda  4.6.1 and 4.5.12.